# how can I skip something in regex?

Tags: php, regex, curl

I want to see all field input and textarea but I don't know how to
show it together in the same code.
and in case I want to skip something for example I want to write
directly input name without make him check the type or I don't want him to show me the readonly so how can I do it ?

```
  <form method="post" action="" id="submit_form">

  <input type="text" name="TITLE" value="" size="40" maxlength="100" class="text" />

  <textarea name="DESCRIPTION" rows="4" cols="36" class="textarea"></textarea>

  <input type="text" name="DESCRIPTION_limit" size="4" class="limit_field" readonly="readonly" value="250" />

  <textarea name="ARTICLE" id="ARTICLE" rows="6" cols="50" class="textarea"></textarea>

  <input type="text" name="META_KEYWORDS" value="" size="40" maxlength="2000" class="text" />
```

```
preg_match_all('/<(input)[\s](type)="?([^>"]*)"?[\s](name)="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]/', file_get_contents($url), $matches);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2453432). Use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or similar instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i know but i have to do it with regex

Comment: May I ask why you _"have to do it with regex"_? It's simply the wrong tool for the job. It's like telling a carpenter that they must use a wrench for hammering in nails. With some extra work, you might get it working, but it's still a bad choice.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code with the line "$string".  Type and Name attributes can be in any order in the input tag, and it searches until it reads a ">" character.

```
    $string = '<input type="text" name="TITLE" value="" size="40" maxlength="100" class="text" />';
    preg_match_all('/<input[^>]*?(?:(type)="([^"]*)")|(?:(name)="([^"]*)")/', $string, $matches);
    if($matches[1][0] == "type" && $matches[3][1] == "name"){
    $type = $matches[2][0];
    $name = $matches[4][1];
    }
    elseif($matches[1][0] == "name" && $matches[3][1] == "type"){
    $name = $matches[2][0];
    $type = $matches[4][1];
    }
    else{
        throw new Exception('no input tags with type and name attributes were found!');
    }
    echo $type;
    echo $name;
```

Comment: this code doesn't work.... i don't want to do it like this for example iwant to look for every code have name or input name but i need him to ignore the type because in preg_match he start match in the order step by step